# Makefile for multiple targets (glob of asm files in directory)

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm new to make. I have a bunch of FOO.32.asm and FOO.64.asm files in a directory. I'd like a Makefile that will assemble each of them to FOO.32.o or FOO.64.o as appropriate, then link each into FOO.32 or FOO.64 executables.

I think maybe static patterns are part of the answer, something like:

```
%.32.o : %.32.asm
    nasm -f elf -gstabs $<

%.64.o : $.64.asm
    nasm -f elf64 -gstabs $<
```

But I'm not sure how to specify the "ultimate" target -- the executables that will depend on the object files. I want to express something like the following:

```
%.32 : %.32.o
    gcc -m32 -o %.32 %.o

%.64 : %.32.o
    gcc -o %.64 %.o
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First find all the source files:

```
src32 := $(wildcard *.32.asm)
src64 := $(wildcard *.64.asm)
```

Next, create targets that depend on the object files, and have an initial rule that depends on both so both are built by default:

```
all: output.32 output.64

output.32 : $(src32:.asm=.o)
        gcc -m32 -o $@ $^
output.64 : $(src64:.asm=.o)
        gcc -o $@ $^
```

And add in your pattern rules above:

```
%.32.o : %.32.asm
        nasm -f elf -gstabs $<

%.64.o : %.64.asm
        nasm -f elf64 -gstabs $<
```

**ETA**

If you want to create one binary per object file that's simple too:

```
src32 := $(wildcard *.32.asm)
src64 := $(wildcard *.64.asm)

all: $(src32:.asm=) $(src64:.asm=) $(src32:.asm=.o) $(src64:.asm=.o)

%.32 : %.32.o
        gcc -m32 -o $@ $^

%.64 : %.64.o
        gcc -o $@ $^

%.32.o : %.32.asm
        nasm -f elf -gstabs $<

%.64.o : %.64.asm
        nasm -f elf64 -gstabs $<
```

That's it!  There are fancier ways to do this that allows you to use only one pattern rule to build objects and one pattern rule to build all executables, but the above is simple and understandable.

If you want to keep the object files to investigate them, you need to add the object files to the `all` target (or, some target: it doesn't have to be `all`), else make will consider them intermediate files and will automatically remove them.  By listing the object files as explicit prerequisites, make knows you want to keep them around.

Comment: Thanks, this is close! Looks like linking is happening once with all object files as input, but I think the linker needs to run once per file -- each will produce an executable. Here's the output I see, when two .64.asm files exist:
`$ make
nasm -f elf64 -gstabs rax-mov.64.asm
nasm -f elf64 -gstabs rax-xor.64.asm
gcc -o output.64 rax-mov.64.o rax-xor.64.o
/usr/bin/ld: rax-xor.64.o:rax-xor.64.asm:5: multiple definition of 'main'; rax-mov.64.o:rax-mov.64.asm:5: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:11: output.64] Error 1`

Comment: Sorry your question wasn't clear.  I thought you wanted to compile all the .o's then link them together into a single executable.  If you want to compile each individual .asm file into a separate executable (so if you have 10 asm files you get 10 executables) why do you want to create the object files?  Why not just build the executables directly from the source?

Comment: Fair question :) I'm learning asm and am enjoying diffing object files produced by slightly different instructions, examining the machine code that is produced. The executables have so much boilerplate, it's just nicer to read through the smaller object files. Sorry for the unclear question.